# Formatting Excel Spreadsheet using Apache POI in JAVA

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My intention is to set the border for the contents of the spreadsheet data while maintaining the other properties of the cell as it is.

The below code formats(setting border) the whole spreadsheet rather than formatting only the portion of spreadsheet where there is actual data.

Is there a reason why the formatting is applied throughout the spreadsheet? And is there a way to overcome this?

```
package learning.selenium.self.begining;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File myFile = new File("TestFile.xlsx");
        Workbook myWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(myFile));
        Sheet mySheet = myWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> r = mySheet.rowIterator();
        while (r.hasNext()) {
            Row myR = r.next();
            Iterator<Cell> c = myR.cellIterator();
            while (c.hasNext()) {
                Cell myC = c.next();
                System.out.println("precessing (" + myR.getRowNum() + "," + myC.getColumnIndex() + ")");
                CellStyle s = myC.getCellStyle();
                s = myC.getCellStyle();
                s.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
                s.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
                s.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
                s.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
                myC.setCellStyle(s);
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        myWorkbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: A cell style is a shared object in POI, so in your code you modify the style that is shared between all cells. Instead, create a new style with borders and set it on the cell. See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Borders for an example.

Comment: Even after replacing the lines
CellStyle s = myC.getCellStyle();
s = myC.getCellStyle();

with the following lines  
CellStyle s = myWorkbook.createCellStyle();
s = myC.getCellStyle();

the result is the same.

Comment: You have to follow the example I linked to. Especially, you have to call `setCellStyle` on the cell using the new style you created.

Comment: each cell has its own CellStyle. I want to preserve the existing cellStyle except border. I can create a new style and set it to the cell, but all the existing style of the cell will be lost.

Comment: See API doc: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html. First create a new Style with `CellStyle newStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();` Then copy the old style with `newStyle.cloneStyleFrom(myC.getCellStyle());`

Comment: Great. This works - newStyle.cloneStyleFrom(myC.getCellStyle()) . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps but is worth checking out

```
CellRangeAddress range= new CellRangeAddress(firstrow, lastrow, firstcol, lastcol); 

RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN, range, sheet);
```

Same way u can set for other borders.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the above code sets the border for the range. My question is more around finding the reason why the border for the entire sheet is changed by running the code in the original post.